# Is there a vim command to move the cursor to the parent bracket?

Tags: vim

Is there a vim command to move the cursor to the parent bracket?

I have a configuration file like this one, and I want to go straight to the parent bracket.  Is there a simple movement command to do this, or is there a way to combine commands to do what I want?

```
PARENT{ // I want to move my cursor here

   CHILD { stuff... }
   CHILD { stuff... }
   CHILD { stuff... }

...

   CHILD { stuff... } // my cursor is on this line
   CHILD { GRANDCHILD { more stuff } }
   CHILD { stuff... }
}
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Yes. Do `[{` in normal mode for that. It might not work for all languages though.

Many move commands are available at `:help [`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out a feature I'd have already been using for years---if only I'd *known* about it. And ]} goes to the closing brace! What a bunch of keystrokes I've been wasting... `:-}

Comment: Hmm. I guess this only goes to the 'current' parent, though(?), so it doesn't exactly do what the OP desired. Is there a variant that pops all the way up or down?

Comment: Thansk! that helps me

Comment: using vim for 8 years still learning new things !

Answer (score 59):

Also you can press % and it will show your open or close bracket

Comment: You must be on the close-brace for the % to work. It is more useful for brace matching rather than navigation.

Comment: @user31986 I think you are wrong there: it works for opening _and_ closing brackets. Actually, it does not only work for the brackets `([{}])` but also for C-type comments `/*...*/`

Comment: @user31986 was essentially correct, though: the question asks to move from the inside of some structure to some parent brace, while this answer is about going _from one symbol_ (parenthesis, bracket or brace) to the matching one. This is related, but is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like `[[` does what you want. And `][` moves to the bottom-most brace. (With many thanks to @Benoit for cluing me in that this might be possible...)

Comment: '[[' & '][' work only when the opening brace is the first char on the line, not when it is as in the question. "PARENT{ "